# FATAL failed to allocate memory

Tags: ruby

Boa tarde,

Estou utilizando a gem rb-libsvm:

> https://rubygems.org/gems/rb-libsvm/versions/1.3.1

Com finalidade de gerar um modelo para classificação de tweets (positivo/negativo).

A partir de uma base de dados com 19000 tweets positivos e 19000 tweets negativos tentei criar o modelo com este código (que é uma adaptação do exemplo de uso que está no github):

```
require 'libsvm'

path = 'pos.txt'
documents = IO.readlines(path).map do |line|
  [1,line.tr("\n","")]
end

path2 = 'neg.txt'
documents += IO.readlines(path).map do |line|
  [0,line.tr("\n","")]
end


# Lets create a dictionary of unique words and then we can
# create our vectors.  This is a very simple example.  If you
# were doing this in a production system you'd do things like
# stemming and removing all punctuation (in a less casual way).
#
dictionary = documents.map(&:last).map(&:split).flatten.uniq
dictionary = dictionary.map { |x| x.gsub(/\?|,|\.|\-/,'') }
training_set = []
documents.each do |doc|
  features_array = dictionary.map { |x| doc.last.include?(x) ? 1 : 0 }
  training_set << [doc.first, Libsvm::Node.features(features_array)]
end

# Lets set up libsvm so that we can test our prediction
# using the test set
#
problem = Libsvm::Problem.new
parameter = Libsvm::SvmParameter.new

parameter.cache_size = 1 # in megabytes
parameter.eps = 0.001
parameter.c   = 10

# Train classifier using training set
#
problem.set_examples(training_set.map(&:first),training_set.map(&:last))
model = Libsvm::Model.train(problem, parameter)
model.save("ic.model")
```

Quando uso uma quantidade menor de tweets para fazer o treinamento (2000 por exemplo) não tenho nenhum problema, mas quando tento fazer com os 38000 tweets ocorre o seguinte erro:

FATAL failed to allocate memory

O erro ocorre no seguinte trecho do código:

```
documents.each do |doc|
  features_array = dictionary.map { |x| doc.last.include?(x) ? 1 : 0 }
  training_set << [doc.first, Libsvm::Node.features(features_array)]
end
```

Sou novo em ruby e não entendi o motivo desse problema, alguém poderia ajudar?

Comment: Não relacionado ao problema, você está lendo o arquivo em "path" duas vezes, quando provavelmente quer ler uma vez o em "path" e outra o em "path2".

Answer (score 1):

O problema é que o pc onde estas a correr esse código não tem memória suficiente para correr o Libsvm com 38000 tweets.

Experimenta reduzir a quantidade de tweets.

Answer (score 1):

Aparentemente você está sem memória. Você está mantendo em memória, ao mesmo tempo:

- A String documents;
- O Hash dictionary;
- O Array features_array;
- O Array training_set;

Pela linha do erro você sabe que conseguiu alocar *documents* e *dictionary*, faltou espaço para *features_array* e *training_set*.

Se for possível (é difícil julgar sem saber exatamente o que os métodos que você está chamando fazem), tente reestruturar o código para usar uma estrutura de pipe.

Ao invés de tentar montar estes na memória, vá chamando .set_examples  durante o loop que você faz em documents.

Outra opção é reescrever esse loop usando documents.pop, assim você vai excluindo os elementos do array e liberando memória.

O ideal seria conseguir ler e tratar um tweet por vez, mais refatoração e não sei se é possível no seu caso.